# User Control Controls not focusing

Tags: c#, winforms

I seem to be having a bit of an issue. I have a user control which i fill in with other controls dynamically.

Here is a sample of the properties I am setting to my dynamically added controls. They are fairly all the same properties across, but differ in control types (which i will describe in a bit). This is in a loop... :

```
Label l_Name = new Label();
l_Name.Name = "lbl_Name_" + info.ID;
l_Name.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
l_Name.Width = width;
l_Name.Height = 20;
l_Name.AutoSize = false;
l_Name.AutoEllipsis = true;
l_Name.Top = this.LastBottom;
l_Name.Left = width;
l_Name.Text = info.NodeName;
l_Name.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
l_Name.Click += Text_Label_Click;
ctrls.Add(l_Name);
```

The disposition of the controls on each row are as follows:

```
 ________________________________________
|Panel   |Label  |Label  |Label  |Panel  |
|  ____  |       |       |       |  ___  |
| |PicB| |       |       |       | |CKB| |
|  ----  |       |       |       |  ---  |
|________|_______|_______|_______|_______|
```

The difference between the other controls and the `Label` definition above is that the `PictureBox` has a `DoubleClick` event, and the `CheckBox` has an `OnCheckedChange` event. The `Panel`s for those input controls are used for displaying the proper borders/sizing/containers.

The problem I am having is that none of the controls except for the `CheckBox` seem to want to focus. Not by clicking, tabbing or using the arrow keys. After debugging quite a bit, it would seem that as soon as a control is clicked on and used, the focus immediately returns to a single specific `CheckBox`.

Is there something I am missing in my definition to ensure that tabbing/focusing on each control is possible? I was expecting to see the traditional dotted border line when a control is focused, especially when using the keyboard, but nothing. Is it because i'm not adding or setting the `TabIndex` property or something like that? I assumed that was set automatically by the renderer...

I implemented the infamous WinPrc function:
`private string GetFocusControl()`
with a messagebox with the control name in order to debug and see who gets the focus, and it's always the exact same checkbox.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That's correct, the only one of those controls that can receive the focus is a CheckBox control. Labels, Panels, and PictureBoxes can't receive the focus. They therefore aren't part of the tab order. It is not something you're doing wrong, it is just part of the design. If you *really* need it, you can do it (see duplicate question). But in general, a control should *not* be focusable unless the user can actually interact with it. No interaction is possible for a Label, it is static unchanging text.

Comment: thanks. I will check out the duplicate because in essence, I am trying to "emulate" the GridView, which does allow you to focus on and manually select a cell. In my instance, I am allowing the user to click on a Label and that triggers an event to replace the label with a textbox for editing, again, much like the GridView. So i would definitely like those controls to be "selectable".

Comment: Do consider replacing the Label with a TextBox then. Just toggle the ReadOnly property (or whatever they call it) to make it editable.

Comment: That's a great idea! Thanks for the help! Please post your last comment as the answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Dupes don't get answers. :-) You're welcome though.